# Weird Skewed Offset in Office

Tags: microsoft-office

For some reason, I have a cut off sign in prompt instead of a generic profile image in the corner.

[image]

Are there any reasons why this offset occurs for all my Microsoft Office programs? How can I fix it?

Comment: Is this Windows 10? If so, I'd blame a graphics bug- they seem to happen frequently.

Comment: No Windows 8. And my graphics work fine.